# Syntax error, unrecognized expression: , $(selector).before(",");

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been using this one line of code for a couple of years now with jQuery 1.2.6.

```
$("#acListTemp div.amenitiesDiv label").before(",");
```

I just upgraded to jQuery 1.6.1 and now it is giving me this error:

> Syntax error, unrecognized expression:
>   ,

I also tried this, but it yielded the same error:

```
theChar = ",";
$("#acListTemp div.amenitiesDiv label").before(theChar);
```

I checked the jQuery API page for the before command, but I'm still stumped.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: check out the `{}` button on the editor to add code, it makes it a bit more readable ;)

Comment: Seems fine to me: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/vHwCJ/).  Are you sure it's this line causing the issue? Using the `@` symbol in 1.3+ causes that error ([source](http://jamesallen.name/index.cfm/2009/3/12/JQuery-selector-problem--Syntax-error-unrecognized-expression-fix)).

Comment: Are you using the fancy quotes, like in the question title?

Comment: @Jeremy Heller - good question, but that'd be a JavaScript syntax error I think.

Comment: @Pointy: He is getting a syntax error.

Comment: Are you sure this is the affected line?

Comment: @Jeremy Heiler: That was my first thought, but they're added automatically in titles on SO. Interestingly (or not) they cause `Syntax error: Unexpected token ILLEGAL` in Chrome.

Comment: I thought that the error was coming from inside jQuery, as if it were trying to parse the string as a selector. If not, well, then you could very well be right.

Comment: @Pointy @Town: Yeah, a selector syntax error does make sense here.

Answer (score 11):

If you're using `.insertBefore()` instead of `.before()`, you'll get that error.

The error doesn't appear using `insertBefore()` in jQuery 1.2.6

---

Looks like the error comes specifically from Sizzle:

https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/blob/master/sizzle.js#L325-327

```
Sizzle.error = function( msg ) {
    throw "Syntax error, unrecognized expression: " + msg;
};
```

...so I'd guess that somewhere in your code you're using `","` as a selector, perhaps in `insertBefore()` or some other method that expects a selector.

---

**EDIT:**

From the comments below, it has been determined that jQuery does *not* fail silently as expected when calling `.before()` against a jQuery object for which no matches are found for its selector.

Seems like a bug to me, but I'm sure the jQuery guys will come up with some reason why this is the desired behavior.

You can see the issue here: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.6.1/src/manipulation.js#L130-140

```
before: function() {
    if ( this[0] && this[0].parentNode ) {
        return this.domManip(arguments, false, function( elem ) {
            this.parentNode.insertBefore( elem, this );
        });
    } else if ( arguments.length ) {
        var set = jQuery(arguments[0]);
        set.push.apply( set, this.toArray() );
        return this.pushStack( set, "before", arguments );
    }
},
```

As you can see, there are only 2 tests.

- The first checks to see if there is at least one element in the jQuery object (and if it has a parentNode). If so, it inserts the content before the matched elements.
- If there were no elements, it just checks to see if any arguments were passed, and if so, it seems to assume that the first one is a selector (or perhaps a tag), and it goes ahead and sends that to the jQuery function.

```
var set = jQuery(arguments[0]);
```

So if you're trying to insert a `","`, but your selector didn't find any matches, jQuery will end up doing:

```
var set = jQuery(",");
```

...which is an invalid expression for Sizzle to process.

Comment: Makes sense; the `insertBefore` function accepts a selector expression. The `,` is a special character in selector syntax.

Comment: Oddly, neither Firefox nor Safari displayed line numbers when it threw the error. I am quite certain that the error is occurring on that line (I have a log statement before the line and another log statement after the line so I am able to isolate the issue to that exact line). So I'm confused by Patrick's answer suggesting that the issue is somewhere else in my script. FWIW this errors too: $(',').insertBefore("#acListTemp div.amenitiesDiv label");

Comment: Given that a `,` is a special character in select or syntax does that mean that I can no longer insert a `,` this way? Can I simply escape it?

Comment: @Dan: It should be no surprise that `$(',').insertBefore("#acListTemp div.amenitiesDiv label");` errors, since you're passing `","` as a selector string, which throws that error. You can insert a `","` just fine. You just can't use it as a selector. You may need to post more code in order to determine the issue. In my tests, it works to do `.before(',')`.

Comment: it's a hotel reservation form, and it's long. Dunno what snippets woult be relevant. [link](http://www.omansion.com/hotel/reservation/rooms.js) line 746 is where the error occurs. (I'm self-taught so apologies if my code stinks!).  It's a 4 page form that errors when you try to submit [link](https://www.omansion.com/hotel/reservation/index2.shtml) (1.2.6 ok though @ index.shtml).  This function grabs a chunk of HTML (the itemized deposit, as quoted to the customer), sanitizes it, then throws it into a text area field so that it can be submitted along with the reservation.

Comment: @Dan: I think I may see the issue. When no results are returned by the selector, it results in that error. This is unusual because typically jQuery methods fail silently when no results are found. Please verify that `$("#acListTemp div.amenitiesDiv label")` is returning the result you expect.

Comment: Thanks Patrick. Now all I need to do is remember what my code was supposed to accomplish! LOL. I will continue researching given your advice. In the meantime I created a much shorter test page (exactly 100 lines) [link](http://omansion.com/hotel/reservation/t.shtml). The error goes away if I comment out line 28. It may be that you are right that no results are found and so it is erring out.

Comment: @Dan: Yep, looks like that's it. There are no more `label` elements there because they've been removed. [Here's the problem code](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.6.1/src/manipulation.js#L130-140) in the jQuery source. Because there's no `this[0]` (no elements matched) it goes to the `else if(arguments.length)`. Because you've passed an argument, it continues in, and the first thing it does is tries to pass your argument (the comma) as a selector. `var set = jQuery(arguments[0]);` Just more jQuery nonsense. I'd submit a bug report but I get tired of their big attitudes over there.

Comment: `if( $("#acListTemp div.amenitiesDiv label").length>0 ){
$("#acListTemp div.amenitiesDiv label").before(",");
}` that fixed it! Thank you so much Patrick, you saved me hours of frustration!

Comment: @Dan: You're very welcome. Please remember to click the large checkmark to the left of this answer if it was helpful. :o)